# "A splendid speech rendered by a girl" -- semantically correct?

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, american-english

> A splendid speech rendered by a girl.

Is the verb "rendered" used here correct? Or is there any alternate verb?

And could anyone suggest if "splendid" used here is the right adjective?

Comment: We normally **deliver** or **give** a speech.  **splendid** is a term of high praise and it can be used as you have used it. **Rendered** is not impossible, but it would be a little unusual.

Comment: I don't want to turn into the voice of political correctness here but to me, a *something* speech delivered by a girl sounds rather patronising...

Comment: What if the sentence is said by a girl?

Answer (score 1):

A marvellous speech was rendered by a girl.

You can use the verb render but it's formal and uncommon in use; you usually give or deliver a speech.

As for the adjective marvellous, you can use it with speech.  Depending on the context, you can also use other adjectives such as great, good, interesting, important, effective, splendid, etc.